# Blazor, set home page to an html page

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a blazor app, but it is divided in 2 parts.
- a web site with several web pages
- a Blazor Application

By default, I wish to navigate to the "index.html" page. This one will have a "login" link
that will redirect to the main application page.

How can I do this... by default I'm directed to the index.cshtml (ie. the blazor app) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I wish to navigate to the "index.html" page.

Assume you have put the `index.html` within the `wwwroot/` folder, you could achieve that by registering a DefaultFiles middleware:

```
app.UseDefaultFiles();    // add this line before invoking app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

...
```

(Note the **order** of middlewares is important)

Or if you want to put `index.html` within a different location, you could pass a custom `FileProvider`  (e.g. [PhysicalFileProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.fileproviders.physicalfileprovider?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)). For more details, see [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1#serve-a-default-document).