# Deploying a C# Blazor application to AzureWebSites but the index is a regular HTML page

Tags: c#, deployment, azure-web-app-service, blazor

So I have a Blazor Project (.Net Core 3.1) that I'm deploying to azurewebsites. When I run the page locally, it starts up on a regular index.HTML page I made. However, on the azure hosting, it starts in index.razor.

How do I make the deployed version start on Index.HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I have deployed my Blazor demo (.net core 3.1). I will show my demo project to u.

[image]

I created login.html under both wwwroot and Pages, but the text inside is different. This way I can distinguish which page is accessed by the Configure method. The only changes I made were to add two login.html and modify the Configure method.

I hope it can help you. If the problem has not been solved, it is recommended to create a demo like me to see if the demo is running properly.

[image]

**PRIVIOUS**

After read your post, I follow the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1#serve-a-default-document) create my Blazor web and modify the `Configure` , then depoly my Blazor app in azure. It works, hope it's useful to u.

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        }

        #region what you needs to be added in your project
        DefaultFilesOptions options = new DefaultFilesOptions();
        options.DefaultFileNames.Clear();
        options.DefaultFileNames.Add("login.html"); //login.html under wwwroot folder
        // For the wwwroot folder
        app.UseDefaultFiles(options);
        #endregion

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
        });
    }
```

There also have a post about this issue, you can refer the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59513089/blazor-set-home-page-to-an-html-page).

Comment: Hi Jason. This works when I run the site locally, however when deployed to Azure it still defaults to index.razor. Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: I think you can create a Blazor app demo to test. I modify my program and it works.@BlazinBlazor

Comment: @BlazinBlazor I have updated my answer, and show you my demo project. If the issue can't be solved,  you  need to crate a demo to test make sure your development env is ok.

Comment: @BlazinBlazor Has your problem been resolved? If you need further assistance, pls let me know.